# Insert text file to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, text-files, delimiter

I'm trying to load data from a .txt file with PHP, but I fail every time.
I tried to convert the text file to a CSV, but even there I fail.
My text file holds the content like this:

```
0001

120PCS LED MOVING HEAD LIGHT

TECHNICAL PARAMETER
Voltage: AC90V-120V or 200V-240V 50-60HZ
Power consumption:400W
Light source:120PCS 1W or 3W LED 
(R:30pcs?G:30pcs,B:30psc,W:30pcs)
Control mode:12HS
Operation mode: master-slave, auto movement,
Sound control: DMX 512
Each led source has an expectancy over 50000 to 100000 hours in theory 
Optical len angle:15 degrees
Level scanning:540 degrees Vertical scanning
270 degrees, speed adjustable 
Indefinite RGBW color mixing system
LCD display adopted
Product size:512*402*555mm
N.W:19kg  G.W:21kg

0002

LED 108PCS MOVING HEAD LIGHT

TECHNICAL PARAMETER
Voltage:AC100V-240V ,50/60HZ 
Power consumption:306W
Light source:108pcs of 1/3W LED 
Operation mode master-slave, sound control,
auto movement,DMX512
Control channel:11Hs
Level scanning angle:540 degrees 
Vertical scanning angle:270degrees 
Quick electronic dimmer, strobe from 1 to 20 times/second
Smooth RGB mixing system &
Rainbow effect(can add white)
Beam angle:15 degrees
Package size :420*330*550mm
N.W:10kg  G.W:13kg
```

I tried to use:

```
 <?php
 $handle = @fopen("data.txt", "r");
 $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
 mysql_select_db("mytext",$conn);
 while (!feof($handle)) // Loop til end of file.
 {
 $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
  // Read a line.
 list($a,$b,$c)=explode("|",$buffer);
 //Separate string by the means of |
 echo $a."-".$b."-".$c."<br>";
 $sql = "INSERT INTO data_table (id, name, age) VALUES('".$a."','".$b."','".$c."')";   
 mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
 }
 ?>
```

But I can't figure out how to insert it nicely.

```
value a = 0001
value b = 120PCS LED MOVING HEAD LIGHT
value c = Technicalparameter etc etc etc

value a = 0002
value b = LED 108PCS MOVING HEAD LIGHT
value c = Technicalparameter etc etc etc
```

I have trouble with delimiters.

Comment: You need to first make the data from the text-file better structured before you do the actual database insertion. First process the text-file into an array for example, then process the array's data to insert it into the database. This will allow you as well to validate the input data before you insert it into the DB.

Comment: Could it be a problem, that your txt-File itself contains commas? (...270 degrees, speed adjustable...)

Comment: whitehat if you can post *exactly* what should be inserted to database from the given sample. It would be clear if you write down output table completely including database layout.

Comment: @cem look at the bottom where it says value a,b,c and then look at the text.Shouldnt be that hard to understand.

Comment: ok, figured out from the solution. so c will contain *all* remaining data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will work, assuming your input file is as shown above. That is:

- Contains 3 fields per record
- Fields in file separated by blank line
- Number of fields in file evenly divisible by 3.

  ```
      <?php
      /* For simplicity in this example, I will assume the db table
       * conforms to the following schema:
       * 
       * CREATE TABLE products(
       *   id VARCHAR(5),
       *   item VARCHAR(100),
       *   item_details TEXT
       * );
       */

      /* Make the db connection */
      $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'user_pwd');
      if (!$link) {
          die('Could not connect to db.');
      }

      // set the db.
      $db_selected = mysql_select_db('test', $link);
      if (!$db_selected) {
          die ("Can't access the db");
      }

      /* Read entire file into string. */
      $fileContents = file_get_contents('f1.txt');

      /* Set line ending character based on particular OS. 
       * Unix       = \n
       * Macintosh  = \r
       * MS Windows = \r\n
       */
      $lec = "\r\n"; // My system is MS Windows.

      /*Fields are separated by a blank line so the delimiter between
       * fields is double line ending character ($lec).
       */
      $delimiter = "$lec$lec";

      /* Build array of field data for all records. */
      $contentArray = explode($delimiter, $fileContents); 

      /* Get the size of the array. */
      $numElements = count($contentArray);

      /* Because we have 3 fields per record, $numElements should be 
       * evenly divisible by 3.
       */
      $numElelemtsPerRec = 3;
      if($numElements % $numElelemtsPerRec > 0) 
        exit("File parse error. Contents of file does not fill records.");

      /* Now build SQL input records. 
       * One record contails 3 ($numElelemtsPerRec) array elements.
       */
      for ($i = 0; $i <= $numElements - 1; $i = $i + $numElelemtsPerRec) {
          $id = mysql_real_escape_string($contentArray[$i]);
          $item = mysql_real_escape_string($contentArray[$i+1]);
          $item_details = mysql_real_escape_string($contentArray[$i+2]);
          $records .= "('$id', '$item', '$item_details'), ";
          echo("id = $id<br>
                item = $item<br>
                item_details = $item_details<br>
                <hr>");
      }

      /* Now trim the ending comma and space from string of records. */
      $records = substr($records, 0, -2);
      //exit($records);

      /* Build and execute the SQL INSERT query. */
      $query = "INSERT INTO products (id, item, item_details) 
               VALUES $records";
      $result = mysql_query($query);

      /* Check for db error. */
      if(!$result) echo("Query Error! Process aborted.");
  ?>
  ```

Comment: THANK YOU @ A Jolly Geek 
A little complexer as i thought but hey it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to `explode` each line with the | character, but I don't see any | in the text! The PHP code looks OK (untested). It's the text input that needs work.

Comment: yes it is the text , i took out previous attempts to not confuse anyone